# JavaScript event.touches array

Tags: javascript, multi-touch

I'm working on a 2 finger gesture using javascript, and I'm facing a problem where I need to know how does the `event.touches` array works. By that I mean if `event.touches[0]` means the first finger pressed or the finger closer to the top of the screen.

In case it means the first one, whats a good way to make `touches[0]` refers to the finger closer to the top and `touches[1]` refers to the non-closer one?

Answer (score 0):

Each .pageX/Y (or .clientX/Y) array contains a touches array which contains a sequential list of the positions traversed between the touchstart and touchend events. So each of those will look roughly like this: [50, 58, 64, 69, 75, ...]

If you're trying to work with multitouch input, you need to look at the TouchList object (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchList). As for identifying the positions of the fingers---you'll have to use the numbers stored in the arrays, and do some math. The touches are created on the TouchList indices sequentially (as fingers touch the screen), not according to touch position.